# YPImagePicker and sending image and video to another controller

Tags: swift

I am trying to send a photo and video from one controller to another with the YPImagePicker pod. I am having an issue understanding how to use this file.

```
var selectedItems = [YPMediaItem]()
let selectedImageV = UIImageView()
     @objc func showPicker() {

    var config = YPImagePickerConfiguration()
    config.library.mediaType = .photoAndVideo
    config.library.onlySquare = true
    config.showsFilters = false
    config.shouldSaveNewPicturesToAlbum = true
    config.albumName = "RecipeSharing"
    config.video.compression = AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
    config.startOnScreen = .library
    config.screens = [.library, .photo, .video]
    config.video.recordingTimeLimit = 5.0
    config.video.libraryTimeLimit = 500.0
    config.video.trimmerMaxDuration = 60.0
    config.video.trimmerMinDuration = 3.0
    config.video.fileType = .mov
    config.showsCrop = .rectangle(ratio: (16/9))
    config.targetImageSize = YPImageSize.original
    config.wordings.libraryTitle = "Gallery"
    config.hidesStatusBar = false
    config.hidesBottomBar = false
    config.library.maxNumberOfItems = 5
    let picker = YPImagePicker(configuration: config)
    picker.didFinishPicking { [unowned picker] items, _ in
        if let photo = items.singlePhoto {
            let finalShareVC = NewInstructionsController()
            picker.navigationController?.pushViewController(finalShareVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
    picker.didFinishPicking { [unowned picker] items, _ in
        if let video = items.singleVideo {
            let finalShareVC = NewInstructionsController()
            picker.navigationController?.pushViewController(finalShareVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My Second Controller has the the code as the following.

```
     var selectedImage: UIImage? {
     didSet {
        guard let image = selectedImage else { return }
        instructionsImage.image = image
    }
}
```

This is used to receive the file the photo I believe. Does anyone know what I have to use to send a photo and video to another controller so that it can be used. I have tried reading a lot on this pod. I get to the save option in this pod and then it does not do anything. I was wondering if anyone had an idea or could help me. Maybe I dont need to push the view but I am unsure. Thank you.

Comment: You are close.  Keep reading other topics.

Comment: You are not sending the video or photo to the other controllers tho. 
Try `finalShareVC. selectedImage =  photo` and keep reading about passing object in ios in other questions

Comment: Ok thank you. I will look at other stuff.